# Chance of arriving first

Tags: probability

I'd like to solve the following homework:

A man and a woman agree to meet at a certain location about 8:30 p.m. If the man arrives at
a time uniformly distributed between 8:15 and 8:45 and the woman independently arrives
at a time uniformly distributed between 8:10 and 9:10, is it possible to find the probability that the man arrives first? If yes, then calculate it.

I'd like to use the graphical method as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/103015/19126), but here the two random variables are distributed uniformly on two different interval sizes.

EDIT: this question is part of a quizz where the possible answers are $\frac{3}{5}$, $\frac{71}{120}$, $\frac{2}{3}$ and "it's not possible".

Comment: This question is almost the same as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255429/joint-probability-involving-uniform-rv).