# The Hurried Duelers brainteaser

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

This question is similar as [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250164/question-on-uniform-distribution) asked in the forum, but I am trying to give it a different twist. Unfortunately, I am not getting to the same answer, so there might be something wrong in my math.

The problem in this case is the following:

*Duels in the town of Discretion are rarely fatal. There, each contestant comes at a random moment between 5 a.m. and 6 a.m. on the appointed day and leaves exactly 5 minutes later, honor served, unless his opponent arrives within the time interval and then they fight. What fraction of duels lead to violence?*

My solution is the following. Let X and Y be uniformly distributed random variables on $[0,60]$, each corresponding to the time of arrival of each dueler. The desired probability is 
$$
P(X + 5 < Y) + P(Y+5<X)
$$
which, by symmetry, equals $2\,P(X+5<Y)$. I have done the following:
$$
2P(X+5<Y) = 2\iint_{X<Y-5}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy = 2\int_5^{60}\int_0^{y-5}\left(\frac{1}{60}\right)^2\,dx\,dy
$$

But this does not lead to the desired probability $\frac{1}{6}$. Is perhaps my approach wrong?

Comment: Check the probability you wrote down in the first equation. The given event is $(X < Y < X + 5\text{ or }Y < X < Y + 5)$, which isn't quite what you wrote.

Comment: How many duelers come within that 1 hour?

Comment: @Iliana: What you wrote corresponds to the event where $X$ leaves before $Y$ arrives or vice versa. (The events are disjoint and so their probabilities add). That works, but you should have $1 - \cdots$ term in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation should be $$1- \displaystyle 2\int_5^{60}\int_0^{y-5}\left(\frac{1}{60}\right)^2\,dx\,dy$$  which would be $1-\frac{55^2}{60^2} \approx 0.1597$ or slightly less than $\frac16$.  I am not sure you have multiplied by $2$ or subtracted from $1$. Perhaps this picture helps

[image]

Comment: @ Henry why not to solve it using just simple geometry where the searched probability is  the difference between the surface of the whole square - 2 * the surface of the white lower triangle  $1-2 \frac{1}{2} (\frac{11}{12})^2=\frac{23}{144} \approx \frac{1}{6}$. Isn't the double integral over complicating the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The condition $X+5 < Y$ actually guarantees there will *not* be a duel.
Similarly for $Y+5<X$.

If you compute your integral correctly, you need to subtract twice the
integral from $1$ to get the probability that there *will* be a duel.

It looks like somewhere you lost a factor of $2$.
The integral itself should be at least $0.42$ and double it should be at least $0.84$.
The probability of a duel turns out to be less than $\frac 16$.

Answer (score -3):

For the violence to occur next man should come in $5$ mins after the first one so the probability of that is $5/60$. but these man can interchange the position so answer will be $2*5/60=1/6$.